# Driver problems with rerunning WIM capture

Tags: mdt-2010

How do I handle driver problems associated with creating a new WIM file using a previously created image as a base?

I am using a custom MDT image which installs Windows 7, Office 2010, etc which was created from a previously deployed base image of Windows 7 + SP 1 + updates.

When the driver injection is enabled I receive a group of messages (collected from different logs, screens, etc). If I turn the preinstall driver injection off things work as expected. If I leave it on I receive the following messages.

- windows cannot install required files
- 0x80004005 8004004
- non zero return code ltiapply rc=31
- Unhandled error returned by LTIApply: a device attached to the system is not functioning. (-2147024865 0x8007001F)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that this problem occurs if the folder C:\Drivers exists within a captured WIM. Using imagex I deleted this directory and C:\Windows.old and the problem appears to be resolved.

Another individual outlines a similar issue [here](http://beccabits.com/2011/05/12/resolution-for-unexplained-failure-of-mdt-2010-inject-drivers-task/).

Comment: Wow. I troubleshot this issue but on Windows 2008 R2 for a solid 2 months awhile back and just gave up on it.  Resorted to using dism and injecting all the necessary drivers manually into the .wim.  Thanks for posting your resolution I will try this.